# Detect value of a property of the object is null

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 100 objects. when a value of a property of the object is null I want to delete the whole object. Right now the if statement is not true, how can I fix this?

object:

```
{ id: 'blockstack-iou',
  name: 'Blockstack (IOU)',
  symbol: 'stx',
  image: 'missing_large.png',
  market_cap_usd: 174267825,
  market_cap_change_percentage: null,
  market_cap_relative_market_cap_percentage: 0 }
```

Code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {

   // console.log(object[i]);
    console.log(Object.values(object[i]));
    //TODO: if one property value of the data is null delete object
    if (Object.values(object[i]) == null) {
        console.log("Null detected and object deleted");
        delete object[i];
    }
}
```

Output of console.log(Object.values(object[i]));

```
[ 'blockstack-iou',
  'Blockstack (IOU)',
  'stx',
  'missing_large.png',
  174267825,
  null,
  0 ]
```

Comment: [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an array.  The result of calling it will never be null. You likely want `Object.values(object[i]).some(i => i === null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the original array to return items where `Object.values(object[i])` doesn't [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `null`.

```js
const object = [
  {p1: 1, p2: 1},
  {p1: 2, p2: null},
  {p1: 3, p2: null},
  {p1: 4, p2: 4}
];

const result = object.filter(o => !Object.values(o).includes(null));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
const noNullPropertiesObjects = arrayWithObjects.filter(obj => !Object.values(obj).includes(null))
```